# Spring Boot method does not exist: Repositories._jr$ip$domainTypeMapping(java.lang.Object, org.springframework.util.ConcurrentLruCache)

Tags: spring-boot

I am in the process of upgrading our Spring Boot application from 2.2.6.RELEASE to 3.1.2. I am using Java 17, Spring Boot 3.1.2, and Spring 6.0.11.  I have gotten to the point that the maven build succeeds. However, I get the following error during startup:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.loadRepositories(Repositories.java:64)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories._jr$ip$domainTypeMapping(java.lang.Object, org.springframework.util.ConcurrentLruCache)'

The calling method's class, org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/home/john/git/aahcs-backend/target/aahcs-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-spring-boot.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar!/org/springframework/data/repository/support/Repositories.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/john/git/aahcs-backend/target/aahcs-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-spring-boot.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar!/org/springframework/data/repository/support/Repositories.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories: jar:file:/home/john/git/aahcs-backend/target/aahcs-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-spring-boot.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar!/


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories
```

The error message says that a method does not exist due to a classpath issue. However, if I'm reading this correctly, the error message also says that the caller and the callee originate in the same jar. What am I missing? How can can a method in spring-data-commons failing to call another method in the same jar be an issue with my classpath?

Any pointers or suggestions are appreciated.

Things I have tried:

1. None of our dependency convergence issues seemed relevant but I fixed them anyway and still got the same error during startup
2. I deleted the spring-data-commons directory in $HOME/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data, re-ran the build, and got the same error at startup
3. I ran the following command: `mvn dependency:tree | grep spring-data-commons` and got the single expected dependency in the output: `[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:3.1.2:compile`
4. I confirmed that spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar exists in the fat jar at /BOOT-INF/lib.

Comment: I have extracted all jar files from the fat jar, expanded them out on the file system, and there is only a single Repositories.class file in the whole project: `./spring-data-commons-3.1.2/org/springframework/data/repository/support/Repositories.class`

Answer (score 0):

Disabling JRebel fixed this error. The method `Repositories._jr$ip$domainTypeMapping` does not exist in the Spring source code and the `_jr` gives away that the method call was agent re-written code(JRebel). It would appear that the version of JRebel Standalone I was using does not support the latest version of Spring Boot. Thank you to the Spring guys for pointing this out to me: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2913